# Can required parameters in a Dart constructor be named?

Tags: dart, parameters, constructor

I am working with some Dart code for a Flutter/Dart class I'm taking. I expected the following code to compile, but it did not:

```
class Person {
  String? name;
  int? age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "name: $name\nage: $age";
  }
}

void main() {
  final person = Person(name: 'Joe', age: 30);
  print(person);
}
```

When I made the constructor parameters optional, as below, it does compile:

```
class Person {
  String? name;
  int? age;

  Person({this.name, this.age});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "name: $name\nage: $age";
  }
}

void main() {
  final person = Person(name: 'Joe', age: 30);
  print(person);
}
```

I tried searching the Flutter dev docs for a reason why this is so, or a way to have required parameters with their names in a constructor, but I didn't find anything. I can certainly imagine cases where I would want required constructor parameters to have names.

My pubspec.yaml specifies the following:
`environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first example uses what are called "positional parameters" in dart. You cannot call a positional parameter with a name label, which is why the first example does not compile.

The second example uses "named parameters". Any parameter defined within `{}` is considered a named parameter and must be called using a name label. As explained in the dart language tour, [named parameters are optional unless they’re explicitly marked as `required`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-parameters).

So simply add the `required` keyword before any named parameter you want to require.

```dart
class Person {
  String? name;
  int? age;

  Person({required this.name, required this.age});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "name: $name\nage: $age";
  }
}

void main() {
  final person = Person(name: 'Joe', age: 30);
  print(person);
}
```

Comment: My bad for missing it in the docs; thanks for tolerating my newbieness!